# Integer solutions of the equation: $x^2+y^2+z^2=kxyz$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given the equation:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=kxyz$$ with:
$(k,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{N}$,
the only solution for $k=2$ is:
$x=0,y=0,z=0$.
For what values of $k$ the equations has solutions in which $x,y,z$ are different from zero? Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution (Theorem 1) here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/32412 though I haven't checked it.

Comment: In the rational numbers there are solutions for any ratio. In the case of integer-only  $k=1$ $k=3$ . Although the formula gives the solution in rational numbers. The whole is a special case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $k=3$ this is the Markov Equation. It has the solution $(1,1,1)$ and from this solution you can build any other by the identification $$(x_0,y_0,z_0) \to (x_0, y_0, 3x_0y_0 - z_0)$$ and by noticing you can permute $x,y,z$.

$$(1,1,1) \to (1,1,2)$$

$$(1,2,1) \to (1,2,5)$$

$$(1,5,2) \to (1,5,13)$$

$$(2,5,1) \to (2,5,29)$$
etc.

Comment: And for $k\ge 4$ ?

Answer (score 0):

You must write the formula, without understanding all the same will not happen!

To show an example. If you will ask is for example $z=1$ You can write infinitely many solutions.

Even such:  $$(1,89,233)$$  $$(1,1597,4181)$$  $$(1,28657,75025)$$  Need to write a formula in General.

For the equation:  $$x^2+y^2+z^2=qxyz$$

The solution, you can write. $t$ - what some integer.

Then using the solutions of the equation Pell.  $p^2-(t^2+4)s^2=\pm1$

The solutions have the form:

$$z=\frac{t^2+2}{q}$$

$$x=\frac{(t^2+2)(p^2-2tps+(t^2+4)s^2)}{qt}$$

$$y=\frac{(t^2+2)(p^2+2tps+(t^2+4)s^2)}{qt}$$

$q,t$ - it is necessary to choose such that decisions were intact.